# Need the animation to start when the page loads without using jquery -> www.mohitarya.co.nf

Tags: html, css

Here is the css I'm using for the horizontal movement.

.hfloating
{

```
animation-name: hfloating;
-webkit-animation-name: hfloating;

animation-duration: 30s;    
-webkit-animation-duration: 30s;

animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

}

@keyframes hfloating {

```
0% {
    transform: translateX(-160%);   
}
50% {
    transform: translateX(170%);
    webkit-transform: translateX(170%);     
}   
100% {
    transform: translateX(-160%);
}
```

}

@-webkit-keyframes hfloating {

```
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-160%);   
}
50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(170%);    
    -webkit-transform: translateX(170%);    
}   
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-160%);   
}
```

}}

Q.Can the .gif file start animating after the page loads?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library. you dont want to use jQuery in particular, or Javascript in general ?

Comment: can it be done with css?

Comment: unfortunately, as css is not a programming language but rather a styling sheet, it cannot know when the page is loaded or not. you have to use javascript.

Comment: I tried the following js code but it's not working     -> <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").animate();
   
}
 </script>

Comment: `.animate()` wont make the page to suddenly animate. you should read how `.animate()` works first. also, this code belongs to jQuery which is a library that you have to link to your page first. your best bet would be only set the classes to your objects after the page loads

Comment: give me a minute i will write an example

Comment: jQuery is an extension library for JavaScript. dont mistake those two. the coding is done with Javascript, jQuery is just an additional .js file that you can include. ill post an answer with example in a sec

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, it cannot be done with css because css is not a programming language, it is just a styling markup.

you have to use JavaScript to achieve the desired result. what you would want to do basically, is just attach the class name to your element after the page is loaded. 

to do so, you need to follow the next steps:

- you do not set a class to your element, but rather an ID so you can find it later
- style your element as the first frame of your animation so it would not be just stuck on the screen
- wait till page fully loads
- attach the class to your element and it will make it run the animations

here is an example (src links are for jsfiddle):

**html:**

```
<div id="test_floater"></div>
<iframe src="/three"></iframe>
<iframe src="/three"></iframe>
<iframe src="/three"></iframe>
<iframe src="/three"></iframe>
```

**Addition to your css:**

```
#test_floater {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-160%);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var floater_temp= document.getElementById("test_floater");
    floater_temp.className = floater_temp.className + " hfloating";
}
```

-- `window.onload` executes after asynchronous content like iframe content is loaded, unlike `document.onload` that runs after the DOM is loaded.

live example:  <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/B3dUA/)**</kbd>

Comment: ok it's working, but see the website (www.mohitarya.co.nf) , it's looking more awkward as the image changes its position on page load and then start animating.

Comment: can the .gif file start animating on page load?? or it starts animating after it loads completely

Comment: you can do the exact same with the gif `src`, just dont set it and use javascript to set the src attribute `theGifElement.setAttribute('src','blabla/blabla/blabla.gif');`

Comment: I did it but see the website (www.mohitarya.co.nf), the image is not loading now

Comment: hmm, the image of the kid? it does load for me... can you make a jsfiddle.net where the issue is shown ?